# Nlog for .NET MAUI sample

Tags: nlog, maui

Is it possible to use **Nlog** in **.NET MAUI**?
There is a sample to configure it? I have not found any sample. Thanks

Comment: Isn't [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog) and  [that](https://github.com/tafuji/Xamarin-Forms-NLog-Sample) what you are looking for ? Maui is based on Xamarin so it should work the same (in theory)

Comment: Example MAUI application can be found here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/tree/master/examples/MauiApp2 . See also tutorial here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I also found that... but for 1st time users, there are a couple of things that are unclear..step 3 references NLog.config... is that a file? can not find any mention of it in the example. Would be awesome with a short example for dummies .. put this here, put that there.. and how to get the log out ...

Comment: @Hans-HenrikMøller Yes the linked tutorial mostly focus on integrating NLog wth MAUI  to existing NLog-users, that already knows what a `NLog.config`-file is. Notice the tutorial also mentions an alternative approach using `WriteToMauiLog()` that doesn't depend on `NLog.config`-file. You are wellcome to create [new issues](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/issues) to suggest improvements

Comment: @RolfKristensen if we do add a NLog.config to the root of the .net MAUI project, how do you register / setup  NLog in MauiProgram.cs?  As the person above mentioned, I am not entirely sure the correct procedure for setting up NLog in .net MAUI

Comment: @SRI You have not mentioned what platforms you expect to support. But if Android / iOS then it is recommended to embed NLog.config as assembly-ressource. And then load NLog.config from assembly-ressource using `LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource`. See also tutorial here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @RolfKristensen .net MAUI....iOS and Android.  I set up NLog for Xamarin but I do not see anywhere how to set up  NLog for .net MAUI ios / Android.  The only exmaples I could find was MetroLog.MAUI....which I have set up but requires me to change how the logging works.....now it will be passed in with DI.  Point being I could not find a specific example of how to set up iOS and Android for .net MAUI

Comment: @SRI You should setup NLog inside `CreateMauiApp` where you can use `LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource` together with `NLog.config`-file as assembly-resource (`Build Action` = `embedded resource`) and then `AddNLog`. See also example here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/blob/master/examples/MauiApp2/MauiProgram.cs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible to use NLog in .NET MAUI. You can start by installing the NLog package in your MAUI project using the NuGet package manager. Once installed, you can configure NLog in the App.xaml.cs file or any other class that will be used throughout your application. Here's an example configuration that writes log messages to a file:

```
public App()
```

{
InitializeComponent();

```
// Configure NLog to write logs to a file
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var fileTarget = new FileTarget("fileTarget")
{
    FileName = "${basedir}/logs/log.txt",
    Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
};
config.AddTarget(fileTarget);

var rule = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

LogManager.Configuration = config;

//...
```

}

The above code defines a new FileTarget that writes logs to a file named log.txt in the logs directory of your app's base directory. The file target is then added to a new LoggingConfiguration, along with a rule that logs any messages with a severity of Debug or higher. Finally, the configuration is set as the default configuration for NLog.
To improve the code, you should consider adding further log targets, such as the DebuggerTarget or ConsoleTarget, to better visualize your logs during development. You can also configure the layout of your log messages using NLog's layout renderer syntax.